# Media Player Control stretch to fit window size

Tags: c#, wpf, size, media-player, windows-media-player

I have the following code to load media and display it using Media Player Control:

```
MediaPlayer Player = new MediaPlayer();
Player.Open(new Uri(videoURI, UriKind.Absolute));
VideoDrawing aVideoDrawing = new VideoDrawing();
aVideoDrawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
aVideoDrawing.Player = Player;
DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(aVideoDrawing);
this.Background = brush;
```

No matter what is the size of the movie I play, it stretches to 1920x1080 (the window size).
I want it to be in the original full size and if the height/width is less then 1920/1080 it will center the video.

Since there's no physical control, I have no Idea how to do it...

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Does `brush.Stretch = Stretch.None;` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add two fields to class level:

```
MediaPlayer Player;
VideoDrawing aVideoDrawing;
```

In constructor add following code:

```
Player = new MediaPlayer();
Player.MediaOpened += Player_MediaOpened;
Player.Open(new Uri(videoURI, UriKind.Absolute));
aVideoDrawing = new VideoDrawing();                    
aVideoDrawing.Player = Player;
DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(aVideoDrawing);
brush.Stretch = Stretch.None;
this.Background = brush;
```

In MediaOpened event handler set appropriate size:

```
void Player_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Player.NaturalVideoWidth <= 1920 && Player.NaturalVideoHeight <= 1080)
        aVideoDrawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, Player.NaturalVideoWidth, Player.NaturalVideoHeight);
    else
        aVideoDrawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
}
```

You must set size in `MediaOpened` event handler because `NaturalVideoWidth` and `NaturalVideoHeight` are not accurate until the `MediaOpened` event has been raised.